# Aggregate - Correct Usage (DDD)

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

I have been trying to get started on Domain Driven Design (DDD) and therefore I've been studying it for a while now. I have a problem and I seek help around how I can solve it in a DDD fashion.

I have a *Client* class, which contains a hell lot of attributes - some of them are simple attributes, such as *string contactName* whereas others are complex ones, such as *list  addresses, list websites, etc*.

DDD advocates that *Client* should be an Entity and it should also be an Aggregate root - ie, the client code should manipulate only the *Client* object itself and it's down to the *Client* object to perform operations on its *inner objects* (addresses, websites, names, etc.).

Here's the point where I get confused:

There are tons of business rules in the application that depend on the *Client*'s inner objects - for instance:

1. Depending on the *Client*'s country of birth or resident and her address, some FATCA (an US regulation) restrictions may be applicable.
2. I need to enrich some inner objects with data that comes from other systems, both internal to my organisation as well as external.
3. The application has to decide whether a *Client* is allowed to perform an operation and to that end, the app needs to scrutinize a lot of client details and make a decision - also, as the app scrutinizes the *Client* it needs to update many of its attributes to keep track of what led the application to that decision.
4. I could list hundreds of rules here - but you get the idea. My point is that I need to update many of the *Client*'s inner attributes. From the domain perspective, the root is the *Client* - it's the *Client* that the user searches for in the GUI. The user cares only about the *Client* as a whole. Say, an isolated address is meaningless - it only exists if it's part of a *Client*.

Having said all that, my question is:

Eric Evans says it's OK for the root to return transient references to inner objects, preferably VOs (keyword here: VO) - but any manipulation on the inner objects should be performed by the root itself.

I have hundreds of manipulations that I need to perform on my clients - if I move all of them to the root, the root is going to become huge - it will have at least 10K lines of code!

According to Eric, a VO should be immutable - so if my root returns VOs, the client code won't be allowed to change them. So doing something like this would be unacceptable in a service: *client.getExternalInfo().update(getDataFromExternalSystem())*

So my question boils down to how on Earth I should update the inner objects without breaking the DDD rules?

I don't see any easy way out.

---

**UPDATE I:**

I've just come across **Specifications**, which seems to be the ideal DDD concept to my problem.

I'm still reading about it but I have decided to post this update anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have been studying DDD for awhile myself and am struggling to master it.

First, you're right: **Specification** is a fine pattern to use for validation or business rules in general, assuming the rules you are applying fit well with a predicate tree.

Of course, I don't know the specifics of your design, but I do wonder about the model itself.  You mention that your Client class has "a hell lot of attributes".  Are you sure your model is not somewhat [anemic](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)?  Could your design benefit from some more analysis, perhaps breaking it out into other Aggregates?  Is this a single Bounded Context?  *Should* it be?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me. It's anemic now - in fact, the application is quite big (and somewhat old) and the entities are all bags for getters and setters. The operations on the objects are performed by services. That's not quite right and that's one of the reasons I was thinking of how I could move the service code around and where I should put it. On being more than one aggregate: I don't think so but I  do need to think about it again - it feels like there should be. Well, yes it's a single bounded ctx - but again, I guess I need to think through again.

Comment: I will bring up this discussion tomorrow in the office and I'll update the question with our insights into this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Specifications is definitely the way to go for complex business logic.

One question though - are you modeling the inner entities like addresses and names as ValueObjects?  The best rule of thumb I can think of for those is if you can say they're equal, without an ID, they're likely value objects.  Does your domain consider names to have a state?

If you're looking at a problem where few entities take in many types of change AND need an audit trail, you might want to also explore EventSourcing.  Ideally the entity declares its reaction to an event, but you can also have the mutating code be held in the event for easy extensibility.  There's pros and cons in that approach, of course.